# save an SMTP session from telnet in a log with a shell script

Tags: bash, telnet

I am creating a script to test an email by HELO ..

Directly in `telnet` console, the commands run fine, but in a script, I can not get the output.

In bash:

```
$ telnet alt1.aspmx.l.google.com 25
HELO verify-email.org
MAIL FROM: <check@verify-email.org>
RCPT TO: <test@gmail.com>
quit
```

results in:

```
root@san [~]# telnet alt1.aspmx.l.google.com 25
Trying 2a00:1450:4010:c09::1a...
Connected to alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mx.google.com ESMTP qm6si6508388lbb.110 - gsmtp
HELO verify-email.org
250 mx.google.com at your service
MAIL FROM: <check@verify-email.org>
250 2.1.0 OK qm6si6508388lbb.110 - gsmtp
RCPT TO: <test@gmail.com>
550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try
550-5.1.1 double-checking the recipient's email address for typos or
550-5.1.1 unnecessary spaces. Learn more at
550 5.1.1  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6596 qm6si6508388lbb.110 - gsmtp
quit
221 2.0.0 closing connection qm6si6508388lbb.110 - gsmtp
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

---

In a script:

```
cat << EOF | telnet alt1.aspmx.l.google.com 25
HELO verify-email.org
MAIL FROM: <check@verify-email.org>
RCPT TO: <test@gmail.com>
quit
EOF
```

---

OR

```
{ echo "HELO verify-email.org"; sleep 1; echo "MAIL FROM: <check@verify-email.org>"; sleep 1; echo "RCPT TO: <test@gmail.com>" ; sleep 1 ;  echo quit } | telnet alt1.aspmx.l.google.com 25
```

---

OR

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn  alt1.aspmx.l.google.com 25
send '"HELO verify-email.org\r"'
send '"MAIL FROM: <check@verify-email.org>\r"'
send '"RCPT TO: <test@gmail.com>\r"'
send '"quit\r"'
```

---

OR

```
sh aa 1> aa.txt 2>&1
```

OR

```
sh aa &> aa.txt
```

---

brings no results.

Comment: `550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist.` seems like a reasonble response. Do you know for certain that `test@gmail.com` is as valid id? Nice Q and well researched/documented. Keep posting! Good luck.

Comment: I agree, this is a great first question. :) Especially impressed that you read the entire Internet. I've been working on that for years and can't seem to get through it.

Comment: Extremely well researched indeed, but I'd hold my enthusiasm about "nice Q", the formulations are literally blasphemous :^) Fortunately, this isn't too hard to fix.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev - "literally blasphemous"? Wow. For what religion? Anyway, the question meets all the requirements of a good question - example code (a few times!), expected output, actual output, explanation. If you disagree with the code or method, there's a <textarea> below with your name on it. Also .. pity you edited the humour out of the question. Fun posts are so much more .. fun.

Comment: @ghoti For the religion of StackOverflow! ^-^ Those runs of symbols that I could barely figure out, with a fair share of superfluous blabber, were insulting my religious feelings >:)

Answer (score 3):

In general, you probably don't want to pipe things into telnet. A reasonable alternative is `netcat` (which is `nc` on most systems).

That said, I wrote [a tiny bash HTTP client](https://serverfault.com/a/683182/104248) a while back, relying on bash's internal support for making TCP socket connections.  An SMTP client is a little more complex, but still fairly easy. SMTP is nice. You can load up a bunch of commands, then just read multiple response lines all at once.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

target="$1"
address="$2"

success=""

# Open a two-way socket connection on fd/3
exec 3<>/dev/tcp/$target/25

# Stand back, we're doing SMTP!
printf "HELO $HOSTNAME\r\n" >&3
printf "MAIL FROM: <$USER@$HOSTNAME>\r\n" >&3
printf "RCPT TO: <$address>\r\n" >&3
printf "QUIT\r\n" >&3

# Now that we've had our say, it's time to listen.
while read -u 3 code message; do
  echo ">> <$code> ${message%$'\r'}"    # Debugging output
  case "$code" in
    2??) success="${success:-true}" ;;  # Only set variable if it's not already set
    5??) success=false ;;               # (i.e. false overrides all other responses)
  esac
done

# Close connections, clean up after ourselves
exec 3<&-; exec 3>&-

if [ -z "$success" ]; then
        echo "NOTICE: Not sure we reached an SMTP server..."
        exit 1
elif $success; then
        echo "NOTICE: All's well, $target accepts mail for $address"
else
        echo "NOTICE: I detected a failure."
        exit 1
fi
```

Note the *Parameter Expansion* of `${message%$'\r'}`, which strips the last character from the line if it is a CR. This is done because SMTP responses use `\r\n` as newlines, whereas your script probably considers the `\r` as merely part of the line (or the $message variable).

Comment: @RodrigoHA FYI, you may wish to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer then.